# Original Fundamental Accounting Data (Not Ratios)

Tags: data, r, fundamentals, accounting

Where do I get original fundamental accounting data from income statement, balance sheet and cash flow statement, like Sales/Revenue, Gross Income, EBIT, Operating Income, Cash & Short Term Investments,  Total Accounts Receivable, Inventories, Cash Flows From Operations, Cash Flows From Investing, Cash Flow from Financing, etc.

Ideally downloadable by an R Interface.

[edit]
Something very important, I have forgotten. I also need the publishing date of the accounting data (which is different from the reporting as of date!), because I want to run a predictive statistical model on it (will otherwise produce an error of future input data). Maybe I have to source the publishing date from another website, in case I cannot get everything out of one hand, maybe also by webscraping from HTML.
[/edit]

Thanks in advance
Consuli

Answer (score 1):

You can pull Financial Statement (Income Statement, Balance Sheet, and Statement of Cash Flows) data from Google Finance with the `getFinancials` function in the `quantmod` R package.

```
> library(quantmod) 
> getFinancials('IBM')
> head(viewFin(IBM.f, type = 'IS'))
Annual Income Statement for IBM
                                       2014-12-31 2013-12-31 2012-12-31
Revenue                                     92793      98367     102874
Other Revenue, Total                           NA         NA         NA
Total Revenue                               92793      98367     102874
Cost of Revenue, Total                      46386      49683      52513
Gross Profit                                46407      48684      50361
Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total      21385      22214      23463
                                       2011-12-31
Revenue                                    106916
Other Revenue, Total                           NA
Total Revenue                              106916
Cost of Revenue, Total                      56778
Gross Profit                                50138
Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total      22865
```

From the quantmod documentation:

"viewFinancials(x, type=c('BS','IS','CF'), period=c('A','Q'),
               subset = NULL)"

the type is for Balance Sheet, Income Statement, and Statement of Cash Flows, and period is Annual or Quarterly.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this:

https://www.quandl.com/data/SF0/documentation/about

BOOMSHAKALA! Includes R (amongst a lot of others) and a full db csv download option.

https://www.quandl.com/tools/full-list